# What's an efficient way to both compress and sort objects by ranking?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, hibernate, sorting

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.0, Spring 4, and JDK 7. So basically I have `Player`

```
class Player
long id
int rank
string name
```

And for instance there are 5 players ordered 1 to 5 respectively.

```
P1 #1
P2 #2
P3 #3
P4 #4
P5 #5
```

Now what I want to do is assign `P3` a rankof `#10`. It would initially be

```
P1 #1
P2 #2
P3 #10
P4 #4
P5 #5
```

But what my desired outcome is this:

```
P1 #1
P2 #2
P4 #3
P5 #4
P3 #5
```

So what I want is for all of those who were previously ranked lower than `P3` to move up (`P4 #4 moves up to #3 and P5 #5 moves up to #4`), and then for the newly assigned `P3` to instead use the next available ranking (`#5`).

So currently what I'm planning to do for example in this case is

```
changeRankRequest(player, rank) {
  int previousRank = player.rank;
  for each p in playerList
    if p.rank > previousRank
      then 
        p.rank += 1 // moving it down the rank
  
  sort(playerList)
  lowestRankingPlayer = findLowestRank(playerList)

  player.rank = lowestRankingPlayer.rank + 1;
  database.batchUpdate(playerList)

}
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way to do so. And it doesn't cater this other case wherein I assign a player to an already taken rank, then all other ranks should shift accordingly.

Comment: One suggestion would be to use larger numbers for the rank in the database, like 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. and convert the database ranks to display ranks, like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. when you retrieve the rows.  When you use large rank numbers, you can insert and change rankings for individual players without having to update the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

can update by sql(mysql):

```
set @x=0;
UPDATE Player  t1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT id,@x:=ifnull(@x,0)+1 as rank 
    FROM Player t
    where t.rank <= #{currentRank}
    ORDER BY t.rank
) t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
SET t1.rank=t2.rank
```

if you need sort all,delete  `where t2.rank <= #{currentRank}`